# Run map/reduce on MongoDb collection with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mapreduce

My understanding of map/reduce seems to be insufficient. I wonder if I can select a subset of documents from a collection and run my map and reduce functions only on that subset.

Is that possible in general?

In case not, it meant, that all filtering has to be done in the map function before emitting. I already wrote a map like that for my usecase:

```
map = <<-EOF
  function(){
    Array.prototype.contains = function(obj) {
      var i = this.length;
      while (i--) {
        if (this[i] === obj) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    };

    project_ids = ['#{@project_ids.map{|pid| pid.to_s}.join('\',\'')}'];

    if(project_ids.contains(this.project_id.toString())) {
      if(this.time.getFullYear() == '#{@year}' && this.time.getMonth() == '#{@month.to_i - 1}') {
        emit(
          this.time.getDate(),
          {
            foos: this.stats.foos
          }
        );
      }
    }
  };
EOF
```

This is part of a Rails project and the method implemented using map / reduce is in fact 3 times slower than a pure ruby method.

So I wonder whether there is any possibility to first filter my set of records applying some conditions and afterwards run the subset of records through map / reduce to get my data.

Can anyone enlighten me?
Thx in advance
Felix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is. One of the parameters of the map/reduce function is "query" which allows exactly what you need. Have a look at http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce for details.

Comment: Remon, many thx. Actually this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an ORM, then you can often obtain the selector from a scoped collection and use that in the map-reduce, e.g. with Mongoid:

```
scoped = Project.active.this_year
Project.collection.map_reduce( ..., :query => scoped.selector)
```